# Nav links move when window goes above certain size

Tags: css, resize, window, nav

I have a horizontal css menu which works and displays fine on smaller screens. Though when you see the site on a larger screen the nav links go from being aligned to the far left(which is correct) to being stepped in.

Why do the nav link move when the screen size increase beyond a certain size?

The site is http://twitterflicker.com

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS to #cssmenu:

```
#cssmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It will be responsive for all resolution.

Comment: This is great thanks mate. It seems to be over hanging the right side by a pixel and a white line running along the top of the nav :-/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `.logo` class. Erase `float: left` there and switch `margin` to `padding`